# Rendering the genie effect to the custom components rendered in the UIView

Tags: iphone, animation, core-animation

How to render the genie effect that we see in the MacOS or in iPhone native transitions, in the custom components that are rendered in the UIView? Any links that describe about the screen transition effects?

Comment: This is a potential duplicate of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app

Comment: Thanks Brad, you've hit the nail right on the head, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brad has given the answer that can be found in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app)

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/Ciechan/BCGenieEffect#bcgenieeffect) is nice lib which provide this effect.