# Minimize window effect of OS X on the iPhone - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, effects

I would like to imitate the minimize window effect of OS X on the UIView's iPhone. I was thinking about making two animations: the first one extend and distort the view and the second one reduce the view!

What do you think? My problem is to distort the view!

Do you have any idea how I could make the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a lot of discussion on this see the response from [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) on [How can I replicate the trashing animation of Mail.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app)

Comment: @ncohen you didnt not properly the answer from Brad, thats the only way you can achieve this