# A question about a animation on IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

It was a beautiful animation when I minimized a window on Mac OS.

The Window was squeeze into the Dock.

I wanted to know that if there is a animation in iOS can do like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is called "suck", and [unfortunately it's still private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664472/uiview-suck-animation) (AFAIK), so you can't use it in apps you want to submit to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

There is something similar on iOS, but the animation gets its view to upper left corner.

```
- (void)cancelHelp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:103 forView:self.view cache:NO];
    [self.helpView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: That's using the private suck effect.

Comment: Ok, so you can use it, I have the same code already on app store.

Comment: ... until Apple adds a check for that. Using private APIs (as this one) is risky.