# How to make delete animation like Notes app

Tags: ios, iphone, animation

I want to make an animation, like the deleting a note in iPhone Notes app. But here I want to do it for Tabbar. So deleting a view (something shows in a view) will swoop down in a delete tab bar icon. Say, I have favourite tab bar item, so adding something in the favourite will swoop down the view in the favourite tab bar item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app) -  I realise the name of the question isn't an obvious link, but it's a good answer for exactly this question.