# how to load nib with different transition style model. has show in figure

Tags: iphone

[image]

how to load view in the above picture.

this code will flipHorizontal.....

```
 SubclassViewController *bNavigation = [[BusinessViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"bNavigation" bundle:nil];
 bNavigation = self;
 bNavigation.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 [self presentModalViewController:bNavigation animated:YES];
 [bNavigation release];
```

Is there any pattern to do..... as show in picture.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do i need to include any animation stuff for the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate question - solution at [How can I replicate the trashing animation of Mail.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app) - but this solution does use private APIs.