# iPhone trash can suck animation

Tags: iphone, animation, bin, recycle-bin

I am trying to use the trash can animation in an iPhone application I am building. I know the feature I need help with is a private API but the app will be in-house.

According to the [iPhoneDevWiki at the toolbar page](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIToolbar) you can activate the trash can opening animation using `[UIToolbar animateToolbarItemIndex:duration:target:didFinishSelector:];`.

After countless hours trying to use this method I could not get it to work. I have changed it so far to the following: `[toolbar animateToolbarItemIndex:1 duration:1.0 target:self didFinishSelector:@selector(done:)];`.

`toolbar` is the name of the `UIToolbar` I created programically using `CGRectMake`.

My button image for the trash can is 1, since it is the second button.

I have tried putting `self` and `nil` in `target` but it doesn't work.

`didFinishSelector` just links to `-(void)done:(id)sender;`.

If I change the `animateToolbarItemIndex` to something that does not exist, the console says that it does not exist. Any ideas to what I have wrong?

Comment: animateToolbarItemIndex does not appear to be a part of the public API.  Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that it is a private API but I would like to use it in a in house app. I have got the suck animation working, but I needed help for the usage of  the trash can animation. Could someone explain how it is used and a example?

Answer (score 0):

The trash can animation works with an array of images, each with the lid closing/opening a little more. So you'd do something like this:

```
UIImageView* trashCan = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
trashCan.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:UIIMAGES, nil];
trashCan.animationDuration = 1.00;
trashCan.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[trashCan startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:trashCan];
```

If you have a google I'm sure you'll be able to find the trash can images to use.