# How to implement delete animation like iPhone's photo app

Tags: iphone, animation, recycle-bin

I have a button of UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash on my Navigation Bar, I want to implement a animation when I clicked that button, with trash open and view flies into the trash. Just like iPhone's Photo or Mail app.

I realize there's [such a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app) been asked on Jan 9 '09. But that one was answered by a private API. As I'm targeting App Store, it's there any safe way to make such animation after years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation you are searching for is called Genie Effect and it does includes a Private API and hence der's no such way direct way to use it...

but may be u can create your own by using key frame Animation. :)

Comment: nope..atleast i didn't come across any of them..
if u do..please post it.. :D

Comment: I cannot understand why Apple make this API private, it's just a cool animation, the system won't be harmed with this...