# Genie effect ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, effect

Does anyone know is there iPad implementation for Genie animation line on MAC OSx? I would like to create some list on the left side and on an action to make "like OSx" Genie animation to animate moving detail section into list item (like minimizing windows on MAC to the dock icon)

Thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of one. There's probably a way to do it, but it's not really in-line with Apple's normal design guidelines for iOS. And any from-scratch implementation will be pretty processor intensive or require something like openGL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest implementation I've found is BCGenieEffect (https://github.com/Ciechan/BCGenieEffect). Not only is the README extremely easy to understand, the actual implementation is just a few lines. Here's an example (found on their README) that displays how to do this simply:

```
CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(30, 40, 50, 60);
[view genieOutTransitionWithDuration:0.7 
                           startRect:startRect
                           startEdge:BCRectEdgeLeft 
                          completion:nil];
```

I just used this in a project and it seems very reliable.

Answer (score 4):

There is [this](https://github.com/rmd6502/Genie) option. There are many stackoverflow posts about this topic, the standard effect uses private API, but can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app).