# Build multiple email delete animation in ios

Tags: ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I replicate the trashing animation of Mail.app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428110/how-can-i-replicate-the-trashing-animation-of-mail-app)

I am trying to mimic the apple multiple email delete animation.  The user selects multiple email on the left side and the emails appears to be stacking on right. I wanted to know if there is any built in animation available that can be used.

[image]

Comment: It's super easy to do this with the collection view in iOS 6. It's not exactly difficult before iOS 5 either, you're just applying a transform to your view and animating the transformation.

Comment: @Till The link gives trash can animation. I am looking for the animation for when you select edit and select multiple email and delete.

Comment: @din did you also check http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIViewAnimationState ?

Comment: Please see my updated question. I am trying to get the stacking effect you see on right side.

Comment: I dont understand why my question was closed saying its a duplicate of mail.app. None of the links given above does not answer my question.